# Does Nginx use .htacess? If not, then how is my WordPress site using .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

I ask this question as I have a WordPress blog on an Nginx server that clearly has an .htacess file; however, I was told by a co-worker that Nginx does not use .htaccess. If Nginx doesn't use .htacess, then what does it use?

Answer (score 1):

Just because there's a .htaccess file in the folder doesn't mean it's being used in any way by nginx.

You can set up nginx to work with WordPress via the nginx configuration files. http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress